# Clonezilla - physical Server

Tags: linux, images, x-server

I have a physical server (HP G9) with three 300GB hard disk drives installed in it. For some reasons, I need to change the physical server's body with HP G7. 
I want to use Clonezilla to make an image of hard disks and restore them again, but:
In new servers, I would have just one 300 GB hard disk. Is it matter for restoring data that the source was (900 GB, Raid 5) three 300 GB HDD and the destination HDD is just one 300GB HDD?!

Comment: Do you have less than 300GB used space?  Also three 300GB disks in RAID 5 should be 600GB not 900GB.

Comment: Yes, the used space is less than 300GB

Comment: I meant I have three HDD each one is 300GB and they are configured as raid 5 . I just want to mention the size of HDDs. Anyway, sorry for mistake. :D

Answer (score 0):

Clonezilla requires the destination drive to be equal size or larger than the source drive.  A way around this would be to shrink the source partition to be equal in size to the destination partition.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I will update you with the result.

Comment: Hi again. you are exactly right. I forced to use Gparted to shrink the partitions, then I could restore the data to destination.